# Python - list data from log and output by group by and count total

Tags: python

I'm new to python, I have /var/log/messages file which I'm trying to figure out how to instead of displaying the whole log just to see how many times a word is in the log, as example, how many times I have DHCP or Apache2 in the log.

My Code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from collections import Counter
logfile = open("putty.log", "r")
count = 1
for line in logfile:
    try:
        #print count
        line_split = line.split()
        #print line_split
        message = line_split[3], line_split[4], line_split[5], line_split[6]
        print message
        count = count + 1

    except:
        print "no data"
```

My logs looks like

Sep  4 14:35:44 (none) serverName:info SERVICE::xxxx[1045]: SERVICE::[VPN-SMU] setStatus(1381): n2n : n2n : check status 5

Sep  4 14:35:44 (none) serverName:notice SERVICE::xxxx[1045]: SERVICE:: xexecve_cmd_with_delay(549): cmd 'ipsec status n2n_1'

Sep  4 14:35:44 (none) serverName:info SERVICE::xxxx[1045]: SERVICE::[VPN-SMU] setStatus(1392): n2n : ipsec status generated result : 000 "n2n_1": 1

Sep  4 14:35:44 (none) serverName:info SERVICE::xxxx[1045]: SERVICE::[VPN-SMU] getNextRemoteEp(230): Nb RemoteEp = 0

Sep  4 14:35:44 (none) serverName:info SERVICE::xxxx[1045]: SERVICE::[VPN-SMU] getNextRemoteEp(235): No Available RemoteEp

Sep  4 14:35:44 (none) serverName:info SERVICE::xxxx[1045]: SERVICE::[TR181DM-WRAPPER] onSet_INT_xxxxx_Established(1432):  onSet_INT_xxxxx_Established  value [false] 

Sep  4 14:35:44 (none) serverName:debug SERVICE::xxxx[1045]: SERVICE::[VPN-SMU] setTunnelInactiveCause(1993): Function 'void vpn_smu::NetToNet::setTunnelInactiveCause()' called

Sep  4 14:35:44 (none) serverName:info SERVICE::xxxx[1045]: SERVICE::[VPN-SMU] setStatus(1604): n2n : Tunnel 'n2n_1' NOT established

Sep  4 14:35:44 (none) serverName:debug SERVICE::xxxx[1045]: SERVICE::[VPN-SMU] updateRoutes(1863): Function 'void vpn_smu::NetToNet::updateRoutes(int)' called

Sep  4 14:35:44 (none) serverName:info SERVICE::xxxx[1045]: SERVICE::[VPN-SMU] setStatus(1647): n2n : m_Counter 5!=1, do no reconnection retry

Sep  4 14:35:48 (none) serverName:debug SERVICE::xxxx[1045]: SERVICE::[VPN-SMU] setStatus(1373): Function 'void vpn_smu::NetToNet::setStatus()' called

Sep  4 14:35:48 (none) serverName:info SERVICE::xxxx[1045]: SERVICE::[VPN-SMU] setStatus(1381): n2n : n2n : check status 6

Sep  4 14:35:48 (none) serverName:notice SERVICE::xxxx[1045]: SERVICE:: xexecve_cmd_with_delay(549): cmd 'ipsec status n2n_1'

Sep  4 14:35:48 (none) serverName:info SERVICE::xxxx[1045]: SERVICE::[VPN-SMU] setStatus(1392): n2n : ipsec status generated result : 000 "n2n_1": 

Sep  4 14:35:48 (none) serverName:info SERVICE::xxxx[1045]: SERVICE::[VPN-SMU] getNextRemoteEp(230): Nb RemoteEp = 0

Sep  4 14:35:48 (none) serverName:info SERVICE::xxxx[1045]: SERVICE::[VPN-SMU] getNextRemoteEp(235): No Available RemoteEp

Sep  4 14:35:48 (none) serverName:info SERVICE::xxxx[1045]: SERVICE::[TR181DM-WRAPPER] onSet_INT_OpenWifi_Established(1432):  onSet_INT_xxxx_Established  value [false] 

Sep  4 14:35:48 (none) serverName:debug SERVICE::xxxx[1045]: SERVICE::[VPN-SMU] setTunnelInactiveCause(1993): Function 'void vpn_smu::NetToNet::setTunnelInactiveCause()' called

Sep  4 14:35:48 (none) serverName:info SERVICE::xxxx[1045]: SERVICE::[VPN-SMU] setStatus(1604): n2n : Tunnel 'n2n_1' NOT established

Sep  4 14:35:48 (none) serverName:debug SERVICE::xxxx[1045]: SERVICE::[VPN-SMU] updateRoutes(1863): Function 'void vpn_smu::NetToNet::updateRoutes(int)' called

Sep  4 14:35:48 (none) serverName:info SERVICE::xxxx[1045]: SERVICE::[VPN-SMU] setStatus(1647): n2n : m_Counter 6!=1, do no reconnection retry

Sep  4 14:35:51 (none) serverName:debug SERVICE::xxxx[1045]: SERVICE2::[SERVICE2-OSM][IPC] recv_SERVICE2_msg(325): Receive request(800) from SERVICE2 application

Sep  4 14:35:51 (none) serverName:debug SERVICE::xxxx[1045]: SERVICE2::[SERVICE2-OSM][SERVICE22XMO] receive_request_get_parameter_values(388): Internal request get path(aaa2)

Sep  4 14:35:51 (none) serverName:debug SERVICE::xxxx[1045]: SERVICE2::[SERVICE2-OSM][SERVICE22XMO] receive_request_get_parameter_values(388): Internal request get path(aaa1)

Sep  4 14:35:51 (none) serverName:debug SERVICE::xxxx[1045]: SERVICE2::[SERVICE2-OSM][SERVICE22XMO] receive_request_get_parameter_values(388): Internal request get path(xxx2)

Sep  4 14:35:51 (none) serverName:debug SERVICE::xxxx[1045]: SERVICE2::[SERVICE2-OSM][SERVICE22XMO] receive_request_get_parameter_values(388): Internal request get path(xxx1)

Sep  4 14:35:51 (none) serverName:debug SERVICE::xxxx[1045]: [XMOS] -> onReceive(386): Receive an XMO request: identifier(838) session's identifier(0)

Sep  4 14:35:51 (none) serverName:debug SERVICE::xxxx[1045]: [XMOR] -> xmor_reply_send(214): Send an XMO reply: identifier(838) session's identifier(1)

Sep  4 14:35:51 (none) serverName:debug SERVICE::xxxx[1045]: SERVICE2::[SERVICE2-OSM][SERVICE22XMO] reply_to_SERVICE2(151): Reply to SERVICE2: XMO request(0x1a03804) XMO code(16777216)

Sep  4 14:35:52 (none) serverName:debug SERVICE::xxxx[1045]: SERVICE::[VPN-SMU] setStatus(1373): Function 'void vpn_smu::NetToNet::setStatus()' called

Sep  4 14:35:52 (none) serverName:info SERVICE::xxxx[1045]: SERVICE::[VPN-SMU] setStatus(1381): n2n : n2n : check status 7

Sep  4 14:35:52 (none) serverName:notice SERVICE::xxxx[1045]: SERVICE:: xexecve_cmd_with_delay(549): cmd 'ipsec status n2n_1'

the output should be like 

SERVICE::xxxx[1045] SERVICE2::[SERVICE2-OSM][SERVICE22XMO] receive_request_get_parameter_values(388): 50 times

SERVICE::xxxx[1045]: SERVICE:: xexecve_cmd_with_delay(549): cmd 'ipsec status n2n_1': 100 times

SERVICE::xxxx[1045]: SERVICE::[VPN-SMU] getNextRemoteEp(235): No Available RemoteEp: 150 times

I'm trying to group the output and count it so I don't have to search the whole log to find out how many times and error is reported.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code which gives you exactly the same results using a regular expression.

```
import re
import string

frequency = {}
document_text = open('log.txt', 'r')
text_string = document_text.read().lower()
match_pattern = re.findall(r'\bapache\b|\bdhcp\b|\bsshd\b', text_string)

for word in match_pattern:
    count = frequency.get(word, 0)
    frequency[word] = count + 1

frequency_list = frequency.keys()

for words in frequency_list:
    print words, frequency[words]
```

Output:
apache 6
dhcp 7
sshd 1

Comment: thanks, that would work, but I'm also after the errors, so I can see how many times I had on SSH failed authentication, and how many times successful authentication, what I'm trying to do is to get a list of how many times apache or any other service was accessed and what was the message level/error/info etc...

Comment: You can do this by reading each line. `with open(r"log.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if "APACHE" in line:
            print line`

Comment: Thanks for help, I'm trying to find out how many times I had a specific error on a service that can be apache, sql or anything, but I'm not trying to see that error 100 times, but one line which should tell me that the error is 100 times in the log file, i'm trying to an output of the /var/log/messages and group the errors by the service (sql/apache/ftp) etc...

Comment: May be this helps [link](https://codehangar.io/smiple-log-and-file-processing-in-python)

Comment: Thank you, I have update the question with part of the log, the log is very complex and I need to be able to group by errors and count the errors.